# Add values of multiple dataframes together cell by cell

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to add multiple dataframes together but not in a bind fashion.

Is there an easy way to overlay & add dataframes on top of each other? As shown in this picture:
[image: picture]

The number of columns will always be same; the row count will differ.
I want to sum the cells by row position. So `Result[1,1] = Table1[1,1] + Table2[1,1]` and so on, such that the resulting frame adds whatever cells have data and resulting table is the size of biggest table's size.

The table are generated dynamically so I'd like to refrain from any hardcoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following two data frames:

```
table1 <- replicate(4,round(runif(10,0,1),2)) %>% as.data.frame %>% setNames(LETTERS[1:4])
table2 <- replicate(4,round(runif(6,0,1),2)) %>% as.data.frame %>% setNames(LETTERS[1:4])
table1
      A    B    C    D
1  0.81 0.08 0.85 0.89
2  0.88 0.82 0.62 0.77
3  0.12 0.13 0.99 0.02
4  0.17 0.54 0.37 0.62
5  0.77 0.10 0.81 0.34
6  0.58 0.15 0.00 0.56
7  0.61 0.15 0.59 0.15
8  0.52 0.36 0.12 0.99
9  0.83 0.93 0.29 0.30
10 0.52 0.02 0.48 0.46
table2
     A    B    C    D
1 0.95 0.81 0.99 0.92
2 0.18 0.99 0.35 0.09
3 0.73 0.10 0.02 0.68
4 0.37 0.53 0.78 0.02
5 0.48 0.54 0.79 0.83
6 0.75 0.32 0.41 0.04
```

We might create a new variable called `ID` from their row numbers and use that to sum the values after binding the rows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
bind_rows(table1 %>% rowid_to_column("ID"),table2 %>% rowid_to_column("ID")) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(),sum))
# A tibble: 10 x 5
      ID     A     B     C     D
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  1.76  0.89 1.84   1.81
 2     2  1.06  1.81 0.97   0.86
 3     3  0.85  0.23 1.01   0.7 
 4     4  0.54  1.07 1.15   0.64
 5     5  1.25  0.64 1.6    1.17
 6     6  1.33  0.47 0.41   0.6 
 7     7  0.61  0.15 0.59   0.15
 8     8  0.52  0.36 0.12   0.99
 9     9  0.83  0.93 0.290  0.3 
10    10  0.52  0.02 0.48   0.46
```

A potentially more dangerous base R approach is to subset `table1` to the dimensions of `table2`, and add them together:

```
table1[seq(1,nrow(table2)),seq(1,ncol(table2))] <- table1[seq(1,nrow(table2)),seq(1,ncol(table2))] + table2
table1
      A    B    C    D
1  1.76 0.89 1.84 1.81
2  1.06 1.81 0.97 0.86
3  0.85 0.23 1.01 0.70
4  0.54 1.07 1.15 0.64
5  1.25 0.64 1.60 1.17
6  1.33 0.47 0.41 0.60
7  0.61 0.15 0.59 0.15
8  0.52 0.36 0.12 0.99
9  0.83 0.93 0.29 0.30
10 0.52 0.02 0.48 0.46
```

Comment: I really like your first approach! If the ID column was already present in the table, how would the function change? (I already have a ID column that we can use for a row by row match - I just took it away in my image for simplification)

Comment: @LovekeshBazaria You can just change `ID` in `group_by(ID)` to whatever the column name is. And then line 1 to `bind_rows(table1, table2)`

Comment: got it - appreciate your help very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create your data frames 
df1<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3),b=c(2,3,4),c=c(3,4,5))
df2<-data.frame(a=c(1,2),b=c(2,3),c=c(3,4))
# Create a new data frame from the bigger of the two 
if (nrow(df1)>nrow(df2)){
   df3 <-df1
} else {
   df3<-df2
}
# For each line in the smaller data frame add it to the larger 
for (number in 1:min(nrow(df1),nrow(df2))){
   df3[number,] <- df1[number,]+df2[number,]
}
```